# Codazon Fastest Theme Menu issue

Tags: magento2, megamenu

I am using Codazon Fastest Theme in my Magento 2 Store. I tried to edit the Main Menu. Suddenly I found that Height of Main Menu is increased.

How can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Any Codazon Fastest Theme user can help in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without having access to the code but my first thought would be it is being added by the WYSIWYG editor.

Navigate to the static blocks related to your navigation and ensure there are no additional lines or paragraphs added.

If you have access to the styling (LESS/SASS/CSS) you could also set `display: none;` on these p tags inside the navigation.